# How can I track Buzzsprout with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track the events from a Buzzsprout Player embedded on my website, to create Goals in Google Analytics?

Do you know if it's possible?

Thank you.

Comment: After looking at it briefly, it looks like it doesn't bother to issue any messages like more popular players do, but I would suggest asking their support and answering your own question. It's good to have answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **UTM parameters** to track interaction in Google Analytics.

Add parameters to URLs to identify the campaigns that refer traffic: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article